# Remote SharePoint 2010 Test Server running on VM

Tags: development, administration, configuration, virtual-machine

Currently I'm looking for a way to improve our test environment. I found it very useful to have a remote SP test server.

So I created VirtualBox VM images for a domain controller and for a SharePoint 2010 web server and deployed VMs onto remote Unix server. I also set up VMs to use an internal network.

Then I configured port forwarding from SharePoint guest VMs to host machine. I forwarded 80 and 8000 ports to 10080 and 18000 ports, so then I was able to access SharePoint site and CA from the Internet. But I met the following problems.

When I'm accessing my SP site `http://example.com:10080` it redirects me to `http://example.com:80/SitePages/default.aspx`. Of course I can access the page directly, i.e. `http://example.com:10080/SitePages/default.aspx`, but the page doesn't seem to work right.

I tried with the following configuration.

`PS> Get-SPAlternateUrl`

```
IncomingUrl                              Zone            PublicUrl
-----------                              ----            ---------
http://spsite                            Default         http://spsite
http://spsite:8000                       Default         http://spsite:8000
```

Port forwarding.

```
Guest    Host
-----    ----
80    -> 10080
8000  -> 18000
```

I also had played with web application extending, but no luck. The current configuration.

`PS> Get-SPAlternateUrl`

```
IncomingUrl                              Zone            PublicUrl
-----------                              ----            ---------
http://spsite:10080                      Default         http://spsite:10080
http://spsite                            Intranet        http://spsite
http://spsite:18000                      Default         http://spsite:18000
http://spsite:8000                       Intranet        http://spsite:8000
```

Port forwarding.

```
Guest    Host
-----    ----
10080 -> 10080
18000 -> 18000
```

So the question is, what am I doing wrong? How can this be done?

Comment: Can you provide the output of Get-SPAlternateUrl?

Comment: @TrevorSeward, of course. I have updated my question.

Comment: You need to make sure that what your clients type in matches an available AAM. Is that the case? And if that is the case (as it doesn't appear to be originally), what is the behavior on the client?

Comment: @TrevorSeward, I have solved my problem. While I was writing a reply to you I managed to find out an issue on our remote server. When I fixed the server, I just used AAM and it works perfectly. Well, understanding a question is half an answer :) Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Post that as an answer, if you could.

Comment: Newbie please listen to @TrevorSeward and add your solution to the problem. It will be helpful for future users. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the following steps.

1. Forward port which is used by SharePoint web server from VM to the host machine. You could use built-in hypervisor port forwarding functionality. Make sure that firewall is configured correctly on the VM and the host machine. After doing this you should be able to access your SharePoint web application from the Internet (but it will not work right).
2. To fix this, configure alternate access mapping for you web application. Go to SharePoint Central Administration -> Configure alternate access mappings -> Edit Public URLs and choose your web application. Add an URL to the Internet textbox.

That's all, it should work now. The process is pretty straightforward, although there can be many possible problems caused by remote server misconfiguration.